# Oracle select max date for all objects in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having a SQL issue.

Basically, I have a list of actions stored in a table called `ACTIONS`. These can happen to  objects which have a unique ID. There can be several actions per object 
What I need to do is select all the objects whose most recent action has the column status on 2.

The Data looks something like this :

```
OBJECT DATE                STATUS
------ ------------------- ------
OBJ1   13/11/2017 16:45:55      1
OBJ1   12/11/2017 15:45:55      2
OBJ2   13/11/2017 06:42:55      2
OBJ2   12/11/2017 16:45:55      1
```

And the output would be : 
OBJ2

The query looks something like this :

```
SELECT ID_OBJECT 
FROM ACTIONS
WHERE LASTACTIONSTATUS = 2
```

I initially tried a sub-query selecting the status of the last action, but my issue is that I can't pass the value of my Object to the sub-query.

Tried fooling around with group by and order by but because there are several objects in the table I can't get all the objects needed

Does anybody have an idea as to how I could go about doing this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a DATE column to determine the *lastest*  action?

Comment: This is not clear. Are you first looking at all actions, select the most recent action for every object (regardless of status), and then select just those where the most recent status is 2? Or are you looking only at the actions with status 2 to begin with, and then for every object that even has **any** actions with status 2, select the most recent one?

Comment: Give some sample data and expected output, else we would keep guessing.

Comment: Sorry for the imprecision.
I added some example data and output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a basic aggregate query. You group by `OBJ`. You have a condition at the group level, which means it should be in the `HAVING` clause. The condition is on the value of `STATUS` for the most recent `DATE`; this is done with the `FIRST/LAST` function (which for some reason seems unfamiliar to many developers, including many experienced ones). https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions065.htm#SQLRF00641

```
with
     test_data ( obj, dt, status ) as (
       select 'OBJ1', to_date('13/11/2017 16:45:55', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 1 from dual union all
       select 'OBJ1', to_date('12/11/2017 15:45:55', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 2 from dual union all
       select 'OBJ2', to_date('13/11/2017 06:42:55', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 2 from dual union all
       select 'OBJ2', to_date('12/11/2017 16:45:55', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 1 from dual
     )
-- End of test data (not part of the solution!) SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select   obj
from     test_data
group by obj
having   min(status) keep (dense_rank last order by dt) = 2
;

OBJ
----
OBJ2
```

Comment: Got to admit, from where I'm standing it doesn't seem basic (just learned three new key words) but it works like a charm.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> select all the objects whose most recent action has the column status
>   on 2

```
SELECT ID_OBJECT 
FROM
 (
    SELECT ID_OBJECT, 
       CASE
         WHEN ROW_NUMBER()        -- most recent row
              OVER (PARTITION BY ID_OBJECT
                    ORDER BY any_column_to_determine_most_recent DESC) = 1
          AND LASTACTIONSTATUS = 2 -- matches status 2
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END AS flag
    FROM ACTIONS
 ) dt
WHERE flag = 1 -- only return matching rows
```

Comment: This is a bit convoluted - why not simply compute the row numbers in the inner query, and then filter for `RN = 1 and STATUS = 2` in the outer query?

Comment: @mathguy: Yes, of course. But your answer is better anyway (I mainly work with Teradata which doesn't support FIRST/LAST).

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following (I didn't test it; there might be some error):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT act1.*
  FROM   actions act1
  WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT act2.*
                     FROM   actions act2
                     WHERE  act2.id_object = act1.id_object
                       AND  act2.action_date > act1.action_date)
) recent
WHERE recent.lastactionstatus = 2;
```